# How to export data table with images as PDF?

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to export the data table content as a PDF, including the images in the first column of every row. I am not sure why the image is not being added to the pdf file after export.

Here is my code:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="/images/listing/{{$lis->image_path}}" width="100px" height="75px" /></a>
```

```
//convert img to base64
function getBase64Image(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    var x = img.onload = function () {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width =this.width;
        canvas.height =this.height;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        callback(dataURL);
        
    };
    img.src = url;
  }
```

the export part:

```
{
    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
    orientation: 'landscape',
    customize: function(doc) {
        //find paths of all images
        var arr2 = $('.img-fluid').map(function(){
          return this.src;
        }).get();
        for (var i = 0, c = 1; i < arr2.length; i++, c++) {
                      getBase64Image(arr2[i], function(result){
                            doc.content[1].table.body[c][0] = {
                            image: result,
                            width: 100
                          }
                          
                      });
                      
                    }
         
    },
 
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ],
        modifier: {
            selected: null
        },
    },
     
},
```

Comment: issue solved using this solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660416/images-pdfmake

Comment: Adding the solution as a duplicate target: [Images & PDFMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660416/images-pdfmake)